# Salesforce Report for - Last to last month

Tags: reporting, formula, dashboard, custom-report-type

I am creating a salesforce report for the last 3 months(Oct, Nov and Dec).

Ex - To retrieve this month data(DEC) I applied - THIS MONTHS filter in Date Field for the field Expiry_date, For Last month(Nov) I used LAST MONTH, Does anyone have any Idea how to get data for October.

The requirement is to create the dashboard individually for all months,So I can't use LAST 90 Days.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [relative filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5) for that: 2 MONTHS AGO. The *n MONTHS AGO* filter covers just one month, starting at 1 for the "previous month" (for now, November), and counting backwards from there.